# Testing if the state reset on key prop change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

I have a functional component that takes key prop. I use the key to be able to re-create the component and all its children when it is changed. I am relatively new to React and JS thus I though of reaching out as I did not found a similar test case.

What I try to accomplish is to assert in my tests that component was in fact re-created on key prop change. As far as I know it is possible with class components as they have provided lifecycle methods like `componentWillUnmount` that you can spy on with Jest.

I would like to do something similar with my functional component. The flow I am looking for is rendering the component -> changing the key prop -> asserting that the components was recreated together with its children.

Is it something possible to do?

Comment: `function MyComponent() { createdCount ++; }`     <- will count how many times `MyComponent` was created, yes, it really is as simple as that.  If you want to count how many times a component was mounted / un-mounted  -> `useEffect(() => { mounted ++; return () => unmounted ++; }, [])`